# Operator << Overload and Const References

Tags: c++, reference, operators, constants

I have a class with a char * as private member data.  I'm passing in an object of the class to an operator overload of <<.  If I don't use a const reference, I get an error stating that the char * is private member data.  If I use a const reference, this error goes away.

Is private member data accessible when an object is passed by const reference and not when it is passed by reference?

Code:

```
// .h file
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Flex
{  
    // The error was caused by having a const in the definition 
    // but not the declaration 
    // friend ostream& operator<<( ostream& o, const Flex& f );  

    // This fixed it
    friend ostream& operator<<( ostream& o, Flex& f );

    public:

    Flex();
    Flex( const char * );
    ~Flex();

    void cat( const Flex& f );

    private:

    char * ptr;
};

// .cpp file
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "flex.h"
using namespace std;

Flex::Flex()
{
    ptr = new char[2];

    strcpy( ptr, " ");
}

Flex::Flex( const char * c )
{
    ptr = new char[strlen(c) + 1];

    strcpy( ptr, c );
}

Flex::~Flex()
{
    delete [] ptr;
}

void Flex::cat( const Flex& f )
{
    char * temp = ptr;

    ptr = new char[strlen(temp) + strlen(f.ptr) + 1];

    strcpy( ptr, temp );

    delete [] temp;

    strcat( ptr, f.ptr );
 }

ostream& operator<<( ostream& o, Flex& f )
{
    o << f.ptr;

    return 0;
}

// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "flex.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Flex a, b("one"), c("two");

    b.cat(c);

    cout << a << b << c;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: With minimal alterations, [compiles fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ddddb3380eeb496). Please produce an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: "I have a class with a char * as private member data."  **Gross.** Use `std::string`

Comment: Why not post your **real code**? The given code just leaves us guessing. Did you have a different typo in your real code, perhaps?

Comment: Okay.  Posted the real code.  When I run that using g++ I get this error: flex.h:18:9: error: ‘char* Flex::ptr’ is private

Comment: Ah wait.  Sorry guys.  Found the issue.  I had a const where it shouldn't have been.

Comment: Your default constructor is broken.

Comment: How so?  It seems to compile fine now.

Comment: @Caulibrot: It compiles, but writes to memory it doesn't own (`new char [0]` returns a valid pointer, but you can't dereference it). Your `cat` is also broken, attempting to use its buffer after deleting it.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I'll edit it.  Please let me know if the edits make sense.

Comment: I wish.  Our professor doesn't allow the use of the string library.

Comment: Your code depends on the buffer being NUL-terminated, so you probably want `ptr[0] = '\0';` instead. `cat` now leaks memory. Oh, and since you haven't initialized the buffer returned from `new`, you really want `strcpy(ptr, temp);` instead of `strcat`. Then put the `delete [] temp;` after that to eliminate the memory leak.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks a bunch.  I'll go work on this some more.

Comment: @Jerry: How's that?  Can you see anything else wrong with it?  I switched it up to passing in a const reference to a Flex object instead of a string for the cat function.

Comment: @Caulibrot: Looks much better.

Comment: Thanks.  That was a big help.

Comment: Please **never** put a using directive in a header. You're also not following the Rule of Three.

Comment: @chris:  Could you please elaborate on why you should never put a using directive in the header?  Our professor hasn't mentioned anything about that.

Comment: @Caulibrot, Anyone who includes your header now gets stuck with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is private member data accessible when an object is passed by const
>   reference and not when it is passed by reference?

Visibility and `const`ness are orthogonal concepts.  You can access `private` members through a `const` reference.

You were quite unclear as to what the actual error you're getting is, or what the real problem is.  However, I'm guessing you have implemented a free `operator<<(ostream&, const MyClass&)` function which somehow attempts to modify `MyClass::ptr` (or some other member variable).

If so, that won't work because the reference is `const`.  Don't modify it's members.